# How to test code with jQuery promises in Mocha?

Tags: jquery, mocha.js, sinon, jquery-deferred, sinon-chai

I have a code that needs to be tested with Mocha.
In a certain part of the code, this is included:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
```

And I am getting this error:

> TypeError: $.Deferred is not a function

I tried to add jQuery to the Mocha tests, and that solved the issue of not knowing what $ was, but still getting an error when calling Deferred.

This is how I included jQuery for the tests:

```
global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery Slim? Deferred objects are not included in that branch.

Comment: I didn't think of that. But that's not the case, we are using full jQuery 3.3.1

Comment: In that case are you certain that the `$` hasn't been hijacked by another library and is still referring to jQuery when the test is run? Try `console.log($ === jQuery)`

Comment: It returns true, with the console.log right before the call to Deferred.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to replicate this then.

Comment: If I put the log before the require: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: That makes sense as jQuery isn't included in the page

Comment: It was just to be sure :D. Thanks for your help anyway